# How to run Tor as proxy for local network

Tags: networking, firefox, proxy, tor

I'm trying to use Tor as standalone socks server available for whole local network.

I've set up connection in my torcc file as follows:

```
#listen on all IPs
SocksListenAddress 0.0.0.0
SocksPort 9150
```

I run the Tor using following windows command:

```
App\tor.exe -f .\Data\Tor\torrc
```

This is how I configured Firefox proxy settings for Tor on my PC (on others computers, I entered my local IP address):

[image: The firefox proxy settings]

On my PC it works, but no remote PC can connect. NMap says that the port is "*FILTERED*".

I confirmed the firewall dialog that popped up the first time I ran the server, saying "Allow".
I also manually added exceptions for port 9150 in firewall settings.

Anything else I can do?

Comment: can you telnet to the port from another host? what does this return in powershell as admin (run on the server)? `netstat -abno | findstr 9150`

Comment: also just a recommendation, Safeplug is the best way to run tor for a whole network, as it doesn't live or die by client proxy configuration. https://pogoplug.com/safeplug Proxy leakage is the biggest vulnerability for tor, and its really really hard to be sure that you aren't leaking somthing (especially DNS queries which give away what you are doing).

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify a *SocksPort* in the *torrc* file on the IP of the network where you want to expose the proxy. Note that the port must be different to the one used for the local connections (9050 by default). Given that the IP address where you Tor runs is *192.168.2.10* you should add:

```
SocksPort 192.168.2.10:9100
```

Also I have set a *SockPolicy* to accept the connections from the local network. Given that your local network is *192.168.2.0 you should add:

```
SocksPolicy accept 192.168.2.0/24
```

Note that, according to the comment in the default configuration, the *SockPolicy* is not needed:

> If no SocksPolicy is set, we accept (and only) requests that reach a
>   SocksPort. Untrusted users who can access your SocksPort may be able
>   to learn about the connections you make.

Answer (score 1):

Set your SocksListenAddress to your local IP address. You can find this using the command ipconfig, then looking for your Ethernet/Wifi adapter.
Then use this same address from the other PCs.

[image]